# Qt signals inheritance?

Tags: qt, signals, signals-slots

**EDIT**: I provided an answer but I'd be happy to accept another one that provides an explanation.

I subclassed `QPushButton` to add some functionality, but after connection the `clicked` signal to a slot, it doesn't get called. If I use a vanilla QPushButton, and don't change anything else, it works. Here's the code:

```
/// --- imagebutton.h

#ifndef IMAGEBUTTON_H
#define IMAGEBUTTON_H

#include <QPushButton>
#include <QImage>

enum ButtonState
{
    Normal,
    MouseOver,
    Pushed
};

class ImageButton : public QPushButton
{
    Q_OBJECT
private:
    ButtonState state;

public:
    QImage *NormalImage;
    QImage *MouseOverImage;
    QImage *PushedImage;

public:
    explicit ImageButton(QWidget *parent = 0);
    virtual ~ImageButton();
    void enterEvent(QEvent *e);
    void leaveEvent(QEvent *e);
    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *e);
    void mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *e);
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *e);

signals:

public slots:

};

#endif // IMAGEBUTTON_H

/// --- imagebutton.cpp

#include <QPainter>

#include "imagebutton.h"

ImageButton::ImageButton(QWidget *parent) :
    QPushButton(parent)
{
    state = Normal;
}

void ImageButton::enterEvent(QEvent *e)
{
    QPushButton::enterEvent(e);
    state = MouseOver;
    this->repaint();
}

void ImageButton::leaveEvent(QEvent *e)
{
    QPushButton::leaveEvent(e);
    state = Normal;
    this->repaint();
}

void ImageButton::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *e)
{
    QPushButton::mousePressEvent(e);
    state = Pushed;
    this->repaint();
}

void ImageButton::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *e)
{
    QPushButton::mousePressEvent(e);
    state = MouseOver;
    this->repaint();
}

void ImageButton::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *e)
{
    QPainter painter(this);

    QImage *pic = NULL;

    switch (state)
    {
    case Normal:
        pic = NormalImage;
        break;
    case MouseOver:
        pic = MouseOverImage;
        break;
    case Pushed:
        pic = PushedImage;
        break;
    default:
        pic = NormalImage;
        break;
    }

    painter.drawImage(0, 0, *pic);
}

ImageButton::~ImageButton()
{
    delete NormalImage;
    delete MouseOverImage;
    delete PushedImage;
}
```

And this is how I connect the signal:

```
void MainWindow::initInterface()
{
    ImageButton *btn_start = new ImageButton(ui->page);
    btn_start->setText("start");
    connect(btn_start, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(btn_clicked()));
    // more buttons connected to the same slot
}
```

What might be the problem here?

Comment: Does connect returns true or false? If it's false what's the console output? It should print some debugging info if it's a debug build.

Comment: It returns true, and no output (although it's a debug build).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling accidentally `QPushButton::mousePressEvent(e)` in your overriden `MouseRelease3vent` method.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it finally. The solution was to put an `emit clicked();` line in the MouseReleaseEvent.

```
void ImageButton::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *e)
{
    QPushButton::mousePressEvent(e);
    state = MouseOver;
    emit clicked();
    this->repaint();
}
```

I still don't know why the call to the superclass' mousePressEvent didn't take care of that. Anyway, it works.

Comment: In your mouseReleaseEvent, you must call QPushButton::mouseReleaseEvent, not QPB::mousePressEvent.